# Flutter Widget Test: AutoRouter operation requested with a context that does not include an AutoRouter

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

I'm using the [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) package in my flutter project and wrapped my App in `MaterialApp.router`.

Now I want to test a widget which calls `AutoRouter.of(context).pop();` in one place.

My test looks like this:

```dart
 testWidgets('my widget test',
     (WidgetTester tester) async {
   await tester.pumpWidget(
     MaterialApp(
       home: MyWidget(),
     ),
   );
 });
```

Pumping the widget understandably throws the following error message:

`AutoRouter operation requested with a context that does not include an AutoRouter. The context used to retrieve the Router must be that of a widget that is a descendant of an AutoRouter widget.`

So I somehow need to provide an `AutoRouter` instance above my widget in my test.

My widget also uses `MediaQuery` and I needed to wrap my tested widget inside `MaterialApp` to avoid an error which was thrown due to `MediaQuery.of(context)` lookup.

I guess I need to do something similar with `AutoRouter` but couldn't figure it out yet. Is there something like a `MockAutoRouter`?

Happy for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I got it working.

`AutoRouter.of(context)` looks up an instance of `StackRouter` which is provided through `StackRouterScope`. So I mocked `StackRouter` and provided it via `StackRouterScope`:

```dart
@GenerateMocks([StackRouter])

...

await tester.pumpWidget(
  StackRouterScope(
    controller: MockStackRouter(),
    stateHash: 0,
    child: MyWidget(),
  ),
);
```

Now `AutoRouter.of(context).pop()` does not throw anymore.

It should also be possible now to stub the `MockStackRouter` and verify if e.g. `pop` is called.

Comment: I tried your approach, but for me, the AutoRouter.push() in my test doesn't work. It still says, "AutoRouter operation requested with a context that does not include an AutoRouter". Do you have a solution for this? Thanks.